# Set default screen in React Native Stack Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am having a problem with the navigation in this app. When logged in, if I navigate to the FAQ screen, then log out, I am not taken to the Login screen, but remain in the FAQ.

I am using multiple `Stack.Navigator` components, depending on the state of the app, i.e. if the user is logged in, if they are logged out etc. The `Stack.Navigator` for when the user is logged out looks as such:

```
     <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={Pages.LOGIN}
        screenOptions={{
          header: ({ navigation, back, route }) => {
            return (
              <Navbar
                navigation={navigation}
                back={back}
                title={route.name}
                navigationOptions={[
                  Pages.LOGIN,
                  Pages.REGISTER,
                  Pages.RECOVER_ACCOUNT,
                  Pages.FAQ,
                ]}
                actions={[]}
                messagesVisible={false}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      >
```

There is no doubt that this `Stack.Navigator` is being returned correctly. But as mentioned, the user remains on the FAQ page even when they log out. I cannot seem to call `navigation.navigate(Pages.LOGIN)` before the `return` of the `Navbar`, and I cannot call it inside the `Navbar` component, I am guessing because at the point in time when log out is pressed, the login screen is not in the stack.

You can also see that I have used ``initialRouteName={Pages.LOGIN}, but this does not seem to work as I had hoped.

Comment: can you share  whole navigation structure `<NavigationContainer> {"Screen components..."}</NavigationContainer>`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to move to LOGIN screen if logout is initiated. So the idea to go with is to create two entirely different stack navigators. and maintain a boolean (isLoggedIn) that switches between the two

You can find more about this approach  here - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/